# How to validate ViewModels derived from an abstract class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, viewmodel

I have the following EditorTemplate

```
@model ESG.Web.Models.FileInfo // <-- Changed to BaseFileInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FileInfoEditorTemplate";
}
<fieldset>
    <table class="fileInfoEdit">
        <tr>
            <td>Base Directory:</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Directory)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Directory)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Filename:</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Filename)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Filename)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

which corresponds to this ViewModel

```
public class FileInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "Directory")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please specify the base directory where the file is located")]
    public string Directory { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify the name of the file (Either a templated filename or the actual filename).")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

}
```

What I want to do is reuse the above EditorTemplate but customise the `ErrorMessage` based on the context the `FileInfo` class is used in. I can have a standard file name eg `abc.txt` or a 'templated' file name eg `abc_DATE.txt` where `DATE` will be replaced with some user specified date. I want an appropriate error message in each case. In essence, *the only difference should be the Annotations.* (I think this the key, but am not sure how to tackle this, thus my convoluted approach!)

I have tried creating an abstract Base view model and then deriving a standard file and templated FileInfo classes. I  change the declaration on the current EditorTemplate to

```
 `@model ESG.Web.Models.BaseFileInfo`
```

and use it like

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.VolalityFile, "FileInfoEditorTemplate")`
```

where `model.VolalityFile` is a `TemplatedFileInfo`. The values are correctly displayed on the Edit page, however, there is no client-side validation when fields are not correctly filled. My initial guess is that this has something to do with the abstract class definition (not having any annotations on the fields).

```
public abstract class BaseFileInfo
{
    public abstract string Directory { get; set; }
    public abstract string Filename { get; set; }
}

// eg of derived class
public class TemplatedFileInfo : BaseFileInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify the name of a templated file eg someFileName_DATE.csv")]
    public override string Filename { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Directory")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please specify the base templated directory where the file is located")]
    public override string Directory { get; set; }
}
```

This is the only way I could think of to tackle my requirement, thus the question - How to validate ViewModels derived from an abstract class? However, if there is another more feasible  way to achieve this, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I had to change the message based the value of another property.

I made the whole validation server side and without the annotations.

Then I just added the ModelErrors this way:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("YourPropertyName", "The Error Message you want to show.);
```

It's a bit extra work and overkill maybe but it did the trick for me.

Comment: You right - it is overkill - thanks for the suggestion though.